# Synchronizing Toolbar Height with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

I have an activity with Toolbar and ViewPager, in the ViewPager there are three Fragments, every Fragment should set different height to the Toolbar which means when the 1st Fragment is the selected Fragment the Toolbar's height should be x and when the 2nd Fragment is selected toolbar height should be y and so.

Now I want the changing of toolbar height to be synchronized with ViewPager scrolling, any advice to do that?

Comment: You can use toolbar for each of your fragment and remove the toolbar from your parent fragment.

Comment: I want to make a touch of beauty by making the changing of toolbar height synchronized with ViewPager scrolling, I mean I don't want to make sudden setting of height

Comment: you can always customize the viewpager if you want smooth transition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Here is Output ..**

[image]

**For Sample Code https://github.com/msquare097/MFlex-toolbar ,....**

First of all nice question and very interesting...
and for implement it.
I have used toolbar minimum height by changing on viewpager scroll.

First of All just declare all `Toolbar` height respect to fragments in your activity where `ViewPager` is implemented.

I have just take it directly as `Integer`. You load it from dimen as DP and convert it to PX.
In my ViewPager I have taken 4 fragment. So declaring 4 toolbar's height.

```
int heightForPage0 = 150;
int heightForPage1 = 400;
int heightForPage2 = 300;
int heightForPage3 = 600;
```

After setting up the adapter just add the listener

**`mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);`**

and override this all three method and write the below code..

```
@Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        Log.d(TAG,positionOffset+"");

        int currentHeight;
        int nextHeight;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                currentHeight = heightForPage0;
                nextHeight = heightForPage1;
                calculateHeightAndApply(currentHeight, nextHeight, positionOffset);
                break;
            case 1:
                currentHeight = heightForPage1;
                nextHeight = heightForPage2;
                calculateHeightAndApply(currentHeight, nextHeight, positionOffset);
                break;
            case 2:
                currentHeight = heightForPage2;
                nextHeight = heightForPage3;
                calculateHeightAndApply(currentHeight, nextHeight, positionOffset);
                break;
            case 3:
                // for last page we don't have to worry about it.
                // bcoz there is no next page available;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
```

and here is that magical method which i have called in `onPageScrolled`..

```
private void calculateHeightAndApply(int currentHeight, int nextHeight, float positionOffset) {
    if (positionOffset==0) {
        return;
    }
    int diff = nextHeight - currentHeight;
        int newHeight = (int) ((positionOffset*diff));
        mToolbar.setMinimumHeight(currentHeight+newHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PageTransformer if you want to use animation.

```
   ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

   pager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View onepage, float position) {
            //Position is the offset of onepage.
            //If position == 0 , one page is center.
            //If position == 1 , one page is on the right of center page.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this code will make sudden changing to the toolbar height, I want the toolbar height to be changed as the user is paging on the ViewPager

Comment: @MoHaKa you can use a PageTransformer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 int X = 30;
 int Y = 50;
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar);

 yourViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pagerChangeListener());

 public ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pagerChangeListener() {
    return new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           if(position == 0){
               toolbar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, X));
             }else{
               toolbar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Y));
             }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of Interface as well.

**Interface:**

```
public interface ChangeToolbarHeight {
    void setToolbarHeight(int height);
}
```

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChangeToolbarHeight
{
public void setToolbarHeight(int height)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mToolbar.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = height;
toolbar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
}
}
```

**Inside your Fragments:**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
     @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
           if (isVisibleToUser)
           {
             ChangeToolbarHeight changeHeightInterface = (ChangeToolbarHeight) getActivity();
             changeHeightInterface.setToolbarHeight(150);
               Log.d("TAG","Current Fragment is visible");
            }
        }
    }
```

set Different height for Each fragment.

SetUserVisbileHint is a default method of Fragment. using this you can find out which Fragment is visible to the user and set the visible fragment toolbar height to the activity.

Main use of this is, viewPager by default loads three fragment, previous one, current selection , and next one to make fling of viewpager smoother.so if SetUserVisibleHint is not checked. your toolbar height will get mixed up. As the viewpager loads framgent of next one in background.

you might have fragment 1 visible but the toolbar height will be set to fragment 3 or fragment 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bannar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/banner_1" />

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bannar"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It works for me. I hope it will work for you, also. thanks